# Float left doesn't work normally

Tags: forms, responsive-design, css-float

I'm trying to make the form responsive.
Here is the link to the form page http://newdev.web-dorado.info/sahakj25/index.php/form
Everything works fine besides the div that contains the two checkboxes.
If the div's size is set to 150px it's not moving down when resizing the page, but if I increase the size to 151px for example it works fine. Can anyone explain what can be the cause of this?

Here is the JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/PcscG/

The div I'm trying to float left is on line 18.

```
<div wdid="2" class="wdform_row">
          <div type="type_checkbox" class="wdform_field">
            <div class="wdform-label-section" style="float:left; width: 150px;"><span class="wdform-label">Checkbox:</span></div>
            <div class="wdform-element-section " style="float:left;">
              <div style="display: table;">
                <div style="display: table-row-group;">
                  <div style="display: table-row-group;">
                    <div style="display: table-row;">
                      <div valign="top" idi="0" style="display: table-cell;">
                        <label id="2_label_element0" class="wdform-ch-rad-label" for="2_element130">option 1</label>
                          <input type="checkbox" id="2_element130" name="2_element130" value="option 1">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: table-row;">
                      <div valign="top" idi="1" style="display: table-cell;">
                        <label id="2_label_element1" class="wdform-ch-rad-label" for="2_element131">option 2</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="2_element131" name="2_element131" value="option 2">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: please show your code, maybe in a Fidlle, not just linking to a page, and hope someone will go true all your code to find an error. needle => haystack

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/PcscG/

The div I'm trying to float left is on line 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the div on line 18 a width. It looks like the width of that div isn't large enough so it has no need to wrap to the next line when you re-size it. If you look closely after re-sizing the page where the 'street address' textbox drops to the next line, the width of that textbox is greater than the width of the div on line 16. Since the div containing the options is an inline-block and only has a width the size of the elements inside of it, and those elements are smaller in width than the 'street address' textbox, it won't wrap.

Here's an example where I gave that div a width: http://jsfiddle.net/Gnax5/

```
<div class="wdform-element-section " style="float:left;border:1px solid blue; width:200px;">
```

You wouldn't need to do this however if your option labels were longer. For example, here's a fiddle with that div having no width, but replacing 'option1' and 'option2' with a longer string: http://jsfiddle.net/sC4dC/